# Is there any way to backtrack the button which called a function using onclick property from that function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working recently on a project where I am adding rows to a table using AJAX , and one of the field is actually a button which will delete that row

```
 $("#question-table").append(" <td class='hovy'> <button 
 class='btn btn-danger delete-button' onclick='jo()'> Delete</button> </td>");
```

I have tried jQuery, but it's not catching the button click event so I tried `onclick` property of a button to call a Javascript function, but the problem is how am I going to track the button that called this function in order to delete that row.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Hint:** function `closest`

Comment: `delete that row` But you're appending a `td`, not a row

Comment: i have tried Jquerry  but it dosen't catch click event for this specific button as it appers later (when page is loaded already)

Answer (score 0):

```
var ajax = {row: 'some row data to render', id: '123'}; // your ajax response
// set the id of the row entry as a param of jo(); and then filter your model by it
var btn = $('<button> Delete</button>').on('click', function(){jo(ajax.id)}); 
$("#question-table").append(btn);
```

checkout MCV pattern and client state

Answer (score 0):

Give this Fiddle a look and see if it helps you out:

```
$('#populateButton').click(() => {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $('#question-table').append(
      $(`<tr id='row${i}'>`).append($(`<td id='td${i}''>`).append(`<button class='btn btn-danger delete button'>Delete Row ${i}</button>`).click(doDelete))
    );
  }
});

function doDelete() {
  this.closest('tr').remove();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2jcypdsn/